# Alternative negative and positive values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called `PROD_COST` with 5 fields:

`(ID, Duration, Cost, COST_NEXT, COST_CHANGE)`

I need extra field called `Groups` for aggregation.

1. Duration = number of days the price is valid (1 day = 1row).
2. Cost = product price in this day.
3. -Cost_next = lead(cost,1,0).
4. Cost_change = Cost_next - Cost.

.

```
+ ID + Duration + Cost + Next_Cost + Cost_change + Groups+
|  1 | 1        | 10   | 8.5       | -1.5        | 1     |
|  2 | 1        | 8.5  | 12.2      | 3.7         | 2     |
|  3 | 1        | 12.2 | 5.3       | -6.9        | 3     |
|  4 | 1        | 5.3  | 4.2       | 1.2         | 4     |
|  5 | 1        | 4.2  | 6.2       | 2           | 4     |
|  6 | 1        | 6.2  | 9.2       | 3           | 4     |
|  7 | 1        | 9.2  | 7.5       | -2.7        | 5     |
|  8 | 1        | 7.5  | 6.2       | -1.3        | 5     |
|  9 | 1        | 6.2  | 6.3       | 0.1         | 6     |
| 10 | 1        | 6.3  | 7.2       | 0.9         | 6     |
| 11 | 1        | 7.2  | 7.5       | 0.3         | 6     |
| 12 | 1        | 7.5  | 0         | 7.5         | 6     |
+----+----------+------+-----------+-------------+-------+
```

I need to group `Groups` field by `Cost_change`. It can be positive, negative or zero.

Some kind guys advised me to use this code:

```
Select 
    id
    , COST_CHANGE
    , sum(Groups) over (order by id asc) +1
from 
    (
    select 
        pc.*,
        (case when sign(cost_change) - sign(lag(cost_change) over (order by id)) between -1 and 1
        then 0
        else 1 -- `NULL` intentionally goes here
        end) Groups
    from Prod_Cost
    ) pc
```

But there is one problem: if there are 0 values between two positive/negative or negative/positive values then it groups it together, for example:

```
 Cost_change Groups
| -5.279    | 33   |
|  5.279    | 34   |
|  0.000    | 34   |
| -5.279    | 34   |
|  0.000    | 34   |
|  5.279    | 34   |
| -8.769    | 35   |
```

I need to have:

```
 Cost_change Groups 
| -5.279    | 33   |
|  5.279    | 34   |
|  0.000    | 34   |
| -5.279    | 35   |
|  0.000    | 35   |
|  5.279    | 36   |
| -8.769    | 37   |
```

Second example:

```
 Cost_change Groups
|  7.574    | 68   |
|  0.000    | 68   |
| -5.279    | 68   |
| -3.490    | 68   |
```

But I need:

```
 Cost_change Groups
|  7.574    | 68   |
|  0.000    | 68   |
| -5.279    | 69   |
| -3.490    | 69   |
```

I would be very grateful for any help.

Comment: Can you have several consecutive zeros (more than one)? Can the first row have zero? What end result should be in these cases?

Comment: You need to provide zeros in your sample data to clarify what you really want to do.  What happens when multiple zeros are in a row?  What happens when the signs are the same on either side?

Comment: @GordonLinoff, hi Gordon, Here's fragment from my data http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=59699169718899539984 (your query). But I need http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=99257550972254124566
You understand me correctly about 0 values, they must be included to +/- values, When my data like -8.2 ; 0 ; 0 ; -8.2 , then your query groups it like: 1 ; 1 ; 1 ; 1 and it's correct because the sequence is : minus ; 0 ; 0 ; minus ". But when my data: -8.2 ; 0 ; 0 ; +7.2, then it must be 1 ; 1 ; 1; 2 becausesequence is: "minus;0;0;plus"  Im not very good in Egnlish, but hope you understand me

Answer (score 1):

Here is [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/37bcf/2/0) with solution.

I'll focus on your problem and leave only relevant columns in the table: `ID` 
and `Cost_change`.

Let's create some sample data that covers all possible cases. I've added few zeros in various places:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (ID int IDENTITY(1,1), Cost_change decimal(10,3));

INSERT INTO @T (Cost_change) VALUES
( 0.000),
( 0.000),
( -1.5),
(  3.7),
( -6.9),
(  1.2),
( 0.000),
( 0.000),
(  2.0),
(  3.0),
( -2.7),
( 0.000),
( -1.3),
(  0.1),
(  0.9),
(  0.3),
(  7.5),
(-5.279),
( 5.279),
( 0.000),
(-5.279),
( 0.000),
( 5.279),
(-8.769),
( 7.574),
( 0.000),
(-5.279),
(-3.490),
(-5.279),
( 5.279),
( 0.000),
( 0.000),
( 0.000),
(-5.279),
( 0.000),
( 0.000),
( 5.279),
(-8.769),
( 7.574),
( 0.000),
( 0.000),
( 0.000),
( 0.000),
(-5.279),
(-3.490);
```

I'll spell out each step explicitly, it makes it easier to understand.

There will be two major parts in processing the data. At first we'll process all non-zero values and generate group numbers for them ignoring zero values. Then for each zero value we'll find the corresponding group number among the generated.

`CTE_Signs` calculates `sign` of `Cost_change` for the current row and for previous row using `LAG` function. Note, that we are filtering out zero values here.

`CTE_Changes` compares signs of current and previous rows and sets `Change` to 1 if they differ. The very first row has `NULL` as a sign of the previous row, `ISNULL` takes care of it.

`CTE_Groups` calculates running sum of the `Change`, which generates group numbers that increase with each `Change`.

This will give us correct group numbers for all non-zero values.

Second major part is getting all zero values and finding correct group number for them using `OUTER APPLY`. Finally `UNION ALL` both parts.

```
WITH
CTE_Signs
AS
(
    SELECT *
        ,SIGN(Cost_change) AS SignCurr
        ,SIGN(LAG(Cost_change) OVER (ORDER BY ID)) AS SignPrev
    FROM @T
    WHERE Cost_change <> 0
)
,CTE_Changes
AS
(
    SELECT *
        , CASE WHEN SignCurr <> ISNULL(SignPrev, SignCurr) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Change
    FROM CTE_Signs
)
,CTE_Groups
AS
(
    SELECT *
        , SUM(Change) OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS Groups
    FROM CTE_Changes
)
SELECT TT.ID, TT.Cost_change, ISNULL(CA.Groups, 0) AS Groups
FROM 
    @T AS TT
    OUTER APPLY
    (
        SELECT TOP(1) CTE_Groups.Groups
        FROM CTE_Groups
        WHERE CTE_Groups.ID < TT.ID
        ORDER BY CTE_Groups.ID DESC
    ) AS CA
WHERE
    TT.Cost_change = 0

UNION ALL

SELECT ID, Cost_change, Groups
FROM CTE_Groups

ORDER BY ID;
```

**Result**

```
ID    Cost_change    Groups
1     0.000          0
2     0.000          0
3    -1.500          0
4     3.700          1
5    -6.900          2
6     1.200          3
7     0.000          3
8     0.000          3
9     2.000          3
10    3.000          3
11   -2.700          4
12    0.000          4
13   -1.300          4
14    0.100          5
15    0.900          5
16    0.300          5
17    7.500          5
18   -5.279          6
19    5.279          7
20    0.000          7
21   -5.279          8
22    0.000          8
23    5.279          9
24   -8.769          10
25    7.574          11
26    0.000          11
27   -5.279          12
28   -3.490          12
29   -5.279          12
30    5.279          13
31    0.000          13
32    0.000          13
33    0.000          13
34   -5.279          14
35    0.000          14
36    0.000          14
37    5.279          15
38   -8.769          16
39    7.574          17
40    0.000          17
41    0.000          17
42    0.000          17
43    0.000          17
44   -5.279          18
45   -3.490          18
```

Comment: That doesn't work, dude. If 0 values between two Positive or two Negative values than it separates them... For example: 2.1 ; 0 ; 0 ; 1.8   Groups: 1 ; 1 ; 1; 2  , But it should be Groups: 1 ; 1; 1; 1;

Comment: http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=86112541269641548360 here you can see . Do you know Russian language?

Comment: I've changed my answer and added more sample data for these cases. Now there is separate logic for non-zero values and zero values. I speak Russian, but on SO everybody speaks English.

Comment: @RussianBear7 Please do consider marking the above as correct answer, if it helped you.

Comment: @RussianBear7, making a correct query is one thing, making a query fast is another. If there are a lot of zeros in the data, a valid efficient solution would be to use cursor. In the future, you should be able to include images to the question - do not post links like you did (my antivirus blocks this site). Even better, post the data as text, so people can copy-paste it into the query. Even better, post sample data as `INSERT` statement. Even better, create [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) with table structure, sample data **and expected result**.

Answer (score 0):

If that table is not too big you can try recursive cte:

```
create table t(id int, v int)

insert into t values
(1, -4),
(2, -3),
(3, 0),
(4, 0),
(5, 1),
(6, 2),
(7, -7),
(8, 9),
(9, 0),
(10, -5)

;with cte as
(select *, 1 as gr, case when v <> 0 then v end pr 
 from t where id = 1
 union all
 select t.*, c.gr + case when t.v = 0 or(t.v*c.v > 0) then 0 else 1 end,
 case when t.v <> 0 then t.v else c.pr end
 from cte c 
 join t on c.id + 1 = t.id
)
select * from cte
order by id
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/92b11/1

Or if numbers of grouping may not be positive or consecutive:

```
;with cte as(select *, ( select case when t.v <> 0 then t.v
                                     else(select top 1 ti.v from t ti 
                                          where ti.id < t.id and ti.v <> 0
                                          order by ti.id desc)
                                end) nv
             from t)
select *, 
       row_number() over(order by case when nv < 0 then 1 else 2 end),
       id - row_number() over(order by case when nv < 0 then 1 else 2 end, id)
from cte
order by id
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/92b11/2